# Functional Dependencies and Normal Forms

Tags: normalization

I'm trying to grasp the concepts of functional dependencies and normal forms, specifically first (1NF), second (2NF), and third (3NF) normal forms. The link [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/723998/can-someone-please-give-an-example-of-1nf-2nf-and-3nf-in-plain-english) was extremely helpful in deciding the distinction between the three forms, but I have a much more abstract problem.

The accepted answer to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/723998/can-someone-please-give-an-example-of-1nf-2nf-and-3nf-in-plain-english) gives wonderful examples of tables and which normal form they are in. However, my question poses the following:

For (**W X** Y Z), determine the form of: WX->Y, WX->Z, Y->Z. (Note: 'WX' should be underlined as the combined primary key, but I couldn't find that in the formatting, so it's bold)

I don't get it; how can I even begin to do this? The textbook I'm referencing only gives concrete examples, and I don't understand the theory well enough to apply it to the abstract. Any insight?

Comment: Are you being asked to determine the normal form for the relation R{ **WX** Y Z }, or the normal forms for { **WX** Y }, { **WX** Z }, and { **Y** Z }? (When you write "determine the form of:...", the *of* usually refers to whatever comes *after*.)

Answer (score 3):

1. 1NF satisfied, as Y and Z depend on the key **WX**;
2. 2NF satisfied as Y and Z depend on the whole key **WX**, and not on any subset of the key;
3. 3NF **not** satisfied as Z depends on Y, which is not part of the key.

To put this into 3NF one would restructure as (**W X** Y) and (**Y** Z).